# Is there a way to reference sweet alert from google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, sweetalert2

I'm linking the library with the src attribute and using a function to call it and its not working

GS:

```js
function doGet(e) { 
  var params = JSON.stringify(e.parameters) 
  var params2 =JSON.parse(params) 
  cache.put("name", params2.name)
  cache.put("DBID", params2.DBID)
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("test").evaluate()
}

function include(f1){ 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(f1).getContent();
}
```

Html:

```html
<head>
  <title>Email form test</title>
  <?!= include("CSS") ?>
</head>
<body>   
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.17.6/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
   <?!= include('Javascript') ?>
   <button type="button" name="Submit" onclick="javascript:t1();"id="sub1"class="btn btn-white btn-animation-1">Submit</button>
```

Calling library (after its been initialized above):

```js
<script>
function t1(){
  Swal.fire('Any fool can use a computer');
}
</script>
```

the expected result should be I click the button and "any fool can use a computer" should pop up in a sweet alert 2 box

Comment: Are you using this in an Apps Script web app? What is your .gs code for evaluating the HTML?

Comment: Thank you. Please update your question with your code as it's difficult to read and understand from comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to import and evaluate the Sweetalert library within Apps Script - you can include it in your HTML file as you would normally and return the HTML Output from file on `doGet()`:

code.gs:

```js
function doGet(e) { 
  // your code here
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
}
```

and index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Email form test</title>
  </head>
  <body>   
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.17.6/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

   <button type="button" name="Submit" onclick="t1();"id="sub1"class="btn btn-white btn-animation-1">Submit</button>
    <script>
      function t1(){
        Swal.fire('Any fool can use a computer');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm evaluating from a template because I'm using separate sheets for CSS & Javascript, I tried to give it its own include function but still not working. is sweet alert compatible with google apps script?

Comment: Not all of ECMAScript 6 is included within Google Apps Script and the issue with using sweet alert directly inside Apps Script is the lack of the WeakMap definition which was defined in ECMAScript 6th Edition and is used by Sweet Alert. At least for the moment it needs to be included in the JavaScript file and evaluated client side.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: That's what I did in my answer, the scriptlets don't work in the Template as they are executed server-side so they need to be evaluated using `createHtmlOutputFromFile`.

Comment: sorry man, I'm new I didn't understand but now I do and its working lol

Comment: @RaphaelCastro No worries! Glad to hear it's all working. Also name, by the way ;)